# Summing Values in an "Association" with the same Keys

Tags: associations

I have a datastructure which is similar to an association:

> [image]

However, it has duplicate "keys" (different entries with the same date) with different values (measured in hours). What I'd like do is sum the hours ("values") for each of the same key (date) to compress the list. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Merge`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Merge.html) to do this,

```
    list = {{a, 1}, {a, 2}, {b, 3}, {a, 7}, {c, 14}, {a, 3}, {c, 5}};
    merged = Merge[Rule @@@ list, Total]
    (* <|a -> 13, b -> 3, c -> 19|> *)
```

You can convert this back to a list of lists easily enough. But if you leave it in this state then you can easily add more data:

```
    merged = Merge[{merged, <|b -> 4|>}, Total]
    (* <|a -> 13, b -> 7, c -> 19|> *)
```

Running `merged[b] += 4` would have the same effect.